# Centering a picture and hiding the tabs

Tags: html, css, polymer

I'm using Polymer 1.x and started using the Polymer Kit to build a current app. I know about the App-Elements, and currently I'm trying to achieve something like this:

Full:
[image]
Mobile:

[image]

So far I have something like this:

[image]
[image]

Do I need to use media queries to hide the tabs and show the logo?

On a side note, I'm really having a hard time understanding Polymer, because I don't know if the elements come with the predefined styles (as Bootstrap or Foundation would do) or you need to do some heavy-lifting in CSS (which is what I've been seeing). I would really appreciate if someone could show me a good tutorial (I've seen Polycasts and the Github) on how to fit things together!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [iron-media-query](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-media-query) to hide the tags.

All the polymer elements have predefined styles and have exposed certain mixins and variables for custom styling.

I would recommend going through polymer's documentation and element's documentation to best understand its usage as each element has its own set of properties and styling. Polycasts cover only a few topics and are good source of knowledge only if you are already familiar with polymer development.

Comment: Thanks. I was using css media queries. iron-media-query could work as well.